# Prove convergence of $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2} + \frac{2}{x_n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $x_1= 1$ and  $$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2} + \frac{2}{x_n}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 1$.  Prove that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges and find its limit.

The hint given says that taking the limit of both sides is only valid if you know the limit exists already.

Part a of the question determines that $ab \leq \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2}$.

I assume we try to use Cauchy along with a trick from part (a)? However, I have no clue how to go about that.  Thank you!

Comment: Why don’t you _assume_ the limit $L$ exists and determine what the limit could be. Then try and show the sequence converges to that value. I find it always helps to know what the value of the limit could be.

Comment: Why we can assume $x_n=1$ and $n\geq 1$?

Comment: I think they mean $x_0=1$. One thing that can be easily noticed is that $2$ is a fixed point of $F(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{2}{x}$.

Answer (score 3):

I restate the question in the general setting.

**QUESTION**

Let $\{x_n\}$ be the sequence given by the following formula:
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{2}{x_n} (n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq 1)
$$
with $x_1\ne 0$. Prove that $\{x_n\}$ converges.

**SOLUTION.**

We consider two cases of $x_1$.

**Case 1.** $x_1> 0$

By induction we have $x_n> 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Using AM-GM inequality we get $x_n\geq 2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, n>1$. Moreover,
$$
x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{2}{x_n}-\frac{x_n}{2}=\frac{4-x_n^2}{2x_n}\leq 0.
$$
Since $\{x_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence and lower bounded by $0$, it converges.

**Case 2.** $x_1< 0$

By induction we have $x_n< 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Using AM-GM inequality we get $x_n\leq -2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, n>1$. Moreover,
$$
x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{2}{x_n}-\frac{x_n}{2}=\frac{4-x_n^2}{2x_n}\geq 0.
$$
Since $\{x_n\}$ is an increasing sequence and upper bounded by $0$, it converges.

**NOTE** We make clear how to use AM-GM inequality in both cases:
$$
x_{n+1}^2=\left(\frac{x_n}{2}+\frac{2}{x_n}\right)^2=\frac{x_n^2}{4}+\frac{4}{x_n^2}+2\geq 2\sqrt{\frac{x_n^2}{4}.\frac{4}{x_n^2}}+2=4.
$$
Hence, $|x_{n+1}|\geq 2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, n>1$.

Comment: Case 1 should be when $x_1>0$. Otherwise it doesn't make sense. $x_n>0$ also. About Case 2, you need to bound it from below, since it's decreasing.

Comment: What is Cauchy Inequality?

Comment: @StammeringMathematician I'm not sure, but I think he meant [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: @StammeringMathematician I have just revised the solution based on your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see here is that your sequence resembles the "Babylonian method" to find square roots.

That is the Babylonians figured out that : $x_{n+1} = \frac 12 (\frac {N}{x_n} + x_n)$ is a sequence that converges to $\sqrt {N}$

In our case 
$x_{n+1} = \frac 12 (\frac {4}{x_n} + x_n)$

We can guess that $\{x\}$ is converging to $2.$

How are we going to prove it?

Show that if $x_n > 2$ then $2<x_{n+1}< x_n$

$x_0 = 1 \implies x_1 = \frac{5}{2}$

For all $n>1$ the sequence monotonic (decreasing) and bounded (below) and therefore convergent.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by Doug M, $x_1 = 5/2$ which is above $2$

Once $x > 2,$ we have $$ 0 < \frac{x-2}{2x} < \frac{1}{2} $$

The interesting thing is how $x-2$ shrinks under your mapping:
$$ \frac{x}{2} + \frac{2}{x} - 2 = \left(\frac{x-2}{2x} \right) (x-2) , $$
so with $x > 2$ we get
$$ \frac{x}{2} + \frac{2}{x} - 2 < \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) (x-2) , $$
with $n \geq 1$ we have
$$ (x_{n+1} - 2 ) < \frac{1}{2} (x_n - 2)  $$

You don't need the next thing: there is actually quadratic convergence.